# PHP Strip <option> Tags and Add <br> to all values

Tags: php, tags, strip

My php knowledge is not enough. Also so sorry for my bad English.
I want to clear all html `<option>` tags and add to all values end `<br/>` tag.

For example:

My Html is:

```html
$str='<option class="" value="">Seçiniz</option><option label="Akü" value="0">Akü</option><option label="Ampul" value="1">Ampul</option><option label="Far" value="2">Far</option><option label="Gösterge" value="3">Gösterge</option><option label="Komple Tesisat" value="4">Komple Tesisat</option><option label="Korna" value="5">Korna</option><option label="Marş" value="6">Marş</option><option label="Regulatör" value="7">Regulatör</option><option label="Röle" value="8">Röle</option><option label="Sağ Kütük" value="9">Sağ Kütük</option><option label="Sinyal" value="10">Sinyal</option><option label="Sol Kütük" value="11">Sol Kütük</option><option label="Stop" value="12">Stop</option><option label="Şarj" value="13">Şarj</option><option label="Valf" value="14">Valf</option>';

echo strip_tags($str);
```

This output is:

SeçinizBalataDiskHidrolikHortumKaliperKolKörüklerPedalTelValfVentilTakım(Komple)

But I want to add line break (`<br/>`) tag to all values.

So my expected result is below:

Seçiniz
Balata
Disk
Hidrolik
Hortum
Kaliper
Kol
Körükler
Pedal
Tel
Valf
Ventil
Takım(Komple)

How can I make this?

Answer (score 1):

May this will work:-

```
preg_replace('/<option>(.*?)<\/option>/', '$1</br>', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without regex:

```
$str = '<option class="" value="">Seçiniz</option><option label="Akü" value="0">Akü</option><option label="Ampul" value="1">Ampul</option><option label="Far" value="2">Far</option><option label="Gösterge" value="3">Gösterge</option><option label="Komple Tesisat" value="4">Komple Tesisat</option><option label="Korna" value="5">Korna</option><option label="Marş" value="6">Marş</option><option label="Regulatör" value="7">Regulatör</option><option label="Röle" value="8">Röle</option><option label="Sağ Kütük" value="9">Sağ Kütük</option><option label="Sinyal" value="10">Sinyal</option><option label="Sol Kütük" value="11">Sol Kütük</option><option label="Stop" value="12">Stop</option><option label="Şarj" value="13">Şarj</option><option label="Valf" value="14">Valf</option>';
$str = str_replace('</option>', '</option><br>', $str);
echo strip_tags($str,'<br>');
```

Second parameter in `strip_tags()` function specify tags which should not be stripped.

Comment: @mitksoft , do this call echo strip_tags($str,'<br>');  removes BR tag from the string ?